# How to populate an objects List<String> member variable with String values using Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, arraylist

A sample of what I need to do.

```
Field field=myBean.getClass().getDeclaredField("listOfStringMemberVar");
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(myBean, value);
//value is a String. I want to add it to the listOfStringMemberVar
```

How do I populate an objects List with String values through reflection?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
field.set(myBean, Collections.singletonList("myvalue")); // for one element list

// if list already exists and you just want to append your value
List<String> theList = (List<String>)field.get(myBean);
list.add("myvalue");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
List<String> list = (List<String>)Field.get(myBean);
list.add(value);
```

Comment: Thanks, useful reply, but @AlexR just explained it little better.

Comment: Also a little bit faster, so no problem :P